# How to select data chronologically up to a certain primary key?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with data and its primary key is a non-integer (UUID to be precise). Each row also contains a timestamp of insertion.

What I want to do is to query the table and obtain the data sorted descending by the timestamp BUT up to a certain primary key.

So if I do `SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY timestamp DESC` I want to get rid of those rows from this result set which were added *chronologically after* a certain primary key.

Is this doable withing a single query in Postgresql 9.4?

Comment: WHERE timestamp >= (select ts for certain primary key...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just add a where clause with a subquery to extract those that were added before the primary key in question:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE timestamp <= (SELECT timestamp FROM data WHERE id = YOUR_ID) ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Or, to select only those records selected after the PK in question:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE timestamp >= (SELECT timestamp FROM data WHERE id = YOUR_ID) ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Remove the '=' in both cases to remove the inclusion of exact match on timestamp (probably just the primary key itself)

Comment: Cool thanks, so you think I'll always need to perform a subquery?

Comment: either a sub-query or two queries, yeah.

Comment: OP wants rows up to a certain date, that would be `timestamp <= (SELECT ...`